# sed - find and replace pattern but exclude specific numeric sequence

Tags: sed, regular-expression

So I have the following statement i made:

```
echo "1234 The few, 7777 the brave." | sed 's/[0-9]\{4\}/(&)/g'
```

which outputs

```
(1234) The few, (7777) the brave.
```

however I want to exclude the 7777 from the pattern matching.

```
(1234) The few, 7777 the brave.
```

question: how do I exclude the 7777 pattern matching?

Comment: Please tell us the rules for why `7777` should be excluded.... You could just use `[0-4]` instead of `[0-9]`, but I somehow doubt that it is what you want.

Comment: Just add `s/(7777)/7777/g` to the script to revert for that specific pattern (if you are sure that there are no `(7777)` sequences in the original file that need to be preserved)

Comment: @Philippos, what if there is a (7777) in the text before that should be kept. I think it is just too unclear to give a good answer.

Comment: I wrote that this case is not covered. If it needs to be covered, you'll need a longer script or a complex ERE, but why bother as long as this requirement is unknown? My suggestion is not good enough for an answer, so I made it a comment. Maybe a helpful one, who knows (-;

Comment: @plumo Thats a great approach I didn't even think of that. But the unfortunate reality is that sometimes the 1234 can include 7 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed has no lookahead expressions that would allow you to nicely skip 7777. But you could do it clumsily by moving all the 7777 matches "out of the way" to some string you're certain doesn't occur anywhere in your input.

For example, if you know #7#7#7#7# doesn't occur in the input, you could use:

```
echo "1234 The few, 7777 the brave." | \
sed -e 's/7777/#7#7#7#7#/g' -e 's/[0-9]\{4\}/(&)/g' -e 's/#7#7#7#7#/7777/g'
```

to get

`(1234) The few, 7777 the brave.`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
echo "1234 The few, 7777 the brave." | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)/(\1)/g' -e 's/(\(7\{4\}\))/\1/g'
(1234) The few, 7777 the brave.

echo "A 1717 B 7777 C 7676 D" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)/(\1)/g' -e 's/(\(7\{4\}\))/\1/g'
A (1717) B 7777 C (7676) D

echo "7777 foo 1234 bar" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)/(\1)/g' -e 's/(\(7\{4\}\))/\1/g'
7777 foo (1234) bar
```

Comment: Why not just offer ```echo "(1234) The few, 7777 the brave."``` as an answer?  Because your answer produces the desired result for the given ***example*** input, but not much else.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I'm sorry, I don't understand :(. What else could I take as input if it is all there is in the question?  My code  cover any instance of the first word and put it between parenthesis. What am I missing?

Comment: As I said, if your only goal is to produce the desired result for the given example input, then `echo` it. But the question doesn’t say “the first word”. And, yeah, the question lacks clarity, and I have voted to close it. But it says `sed 's/[0-9]\{4\}/(&)/g'` and “exclude the 7777 from the pattern matching”, so I suggest that it’s safe to assume that ```A 1717 B 7777 C 7676 D``` should be changed to ```A (1717) B 7777 C (7676) D```.

Comment: Oh, also `7777 foo 1234 bar` should be changed to `7777 foo (1234) bar`.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll vote to close it also. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Although I voted to close, I didn't want to leave the answer as it was. Updated to match your suggestions.

Comment: OK.  (1) You don’t need to say ``[7-7]\{4\}``; you could simplify that to ``7\{4\}`` or even just `7777`.  (2) Your second substitute (s) command also needs to end with `/g` to handle `7777 hours, 1234 minutes, 7777 seconds`.  (3) Be aware that both your answer and the other one may need to be hardened if the OP ever specifies how numbers of *more than* four digits should be handle (`I’ve got 17777 bottles of beer on the wall, and I need to make them last 77771 days.`)  It potentially gets even more interesting if eight-digit numbers are allowed.    :-)    ⁠